# Which jar deploys Hibernate 5.1 class org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl?

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x

I'm trying to configure JBoss AS 7.1.3 to support Hibernate **5.1.10.Final**, since this version has a fix for a bug in my application. It's **not possible** (please don't insist) to upgrade to WildFly at this moment.

A new JBoss module for version **5.1.10.Final** was created as shown below:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.hibernate" slot="5.1.10.Final">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-core-5.1.10.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.10.Final.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="hibernate-infinispan-5.1.10.Final.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="asm.asm"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.persistence.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.validation.api"/>
        <module name="org.antlr"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
        <module name="org.dom4j"/>
        <module name="org.infinispan" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.javassist"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate" slot="5" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.envers" services="import" optional="true"/>
        <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

The `persistence.xml` was configured to make use the **5.1.10.Final** version, as shown below:

```
<persistence-unit name="myunit" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/env/jdbc/SCA</jta-data-source>

    <!-- Many occurences of <class/> -->
    <class>...</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.JBossAppServerJtaPlatform" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect" />
        <property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.1.10.Final"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And my `pom.xml` was also configured to depend on the **5.1.10.Final** version, as shown below:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.10.Final</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The application was deployed to use the **5.1.10.Final** version thanks to the file `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` as below:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main" />
        </exclusions>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.hibernate" slot="5.1.10.Final" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

After all that, I can deploy my application to JBoss, but during its load I receive the following error:

```
11:31:29,815 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."sca.war#sca": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."sca.war#sca": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: sca] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:100) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA.jar:2.0.0.GA]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: sca] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:197) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$500(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:96) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.3.Final.jar:7.1.3.Final]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate dialect class
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2279)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2275)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1744)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect cannot be cast to org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:73)
    ... 20 more
```

Considering that class `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect` is a subclass of `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect` (I checked in the source code), it seems to me that I'm having some mixed version problem here. The cast happens in `org.hibernate.service.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect()` method, but I don't know which jar deploys that class in order to correct it's version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging, I found some light in a page inside [WildFly documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-UpdateyourPersistence.xmlforHibernate5.0).

So, I changed a line of Hibernate properties in the `persistence.xml` file, replacing:

```
<property name="jboss.as.jpa.providerModule" value="org.hibernate:5.1.10.Final"/>
```

by

```
<property name="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider" value="org.hibernate:5.1.10.Final"/>
```

That made JBoss load without any error and the persistence unit was correctly build.

Answer (score 0):

All looks good in your conf., Oracle12cDialect, Dialect and DialectFactoryImpl comes from the same hibernate-core.jar so there should be no such concern.

But check that there not multiple version of hibernate-core in your classpath.

You may run maven-duplicate-finder-plugin maven plugin to check if `org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect` appears twice like that :

```
mvn com.ning.maven.plugins:maven-duplicate-finder-plugin:1.0.9:check
```

Comment: Good tip, but not helpful for me! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

> org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect cannot be cast to org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect

This is nonsense since Oracle12cDialect implements Dialect. But ...

### The problem

... there is hope! We have at least three classloaders in a hierarchy.

```
               [classloader-base]                            (without hibernate)
                 |            |
 [classloader modul1]     [classloader modul2]               (with hibernate)
```

Whearat classloader modul1 and modul2 loads the hibernate-jars (in the same version of course), classloader-base dont!

The modul1 and the modul2 have their **very own copy** of the Dialect-interface, so they are incompatible.

If now, modul1 have a field in a class like this:

```
       (modul 1)
public Dialect foobarDialect;
```

But modul 2 creates the instance like this:

```
       (modul 2)
setFoobarDialect(new Oracle12cDialect());
```

Because modul1 have its own version of the dialect that differs in-load from the version of the dialect of modul2 its incompatible.

### Problem in a nut-shell

Lets make a small experiment:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File maven = new File("C:/Users/Guest/.m2/repository/");
    String hbm = "org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.1.Final/hibernate-core-5.2.1.Final.jar";
    String jpa = "org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar";
    String logging = "org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar";
    String jta = "javax/transaction/jta/1.1/jta-1.1.jar";
    URL[] urls = new URL[] {
        new File(maven, hbm).toURL(), 
        new File(maven, jpa).toURL(),
        new File(maven, logging).toURL(), 
        new File(maven, jta).toURL()
    };
    ClassLoader module1 = new URLClassLoader(urls);
    ClassLoader module2 = new URLClassLoader(urls);
    Class dialect = module1.loadClass("org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect");
    Class interfac = module2.loadClass("org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect");
    System.out.println(interfac.toString());
    System.out.println(dialect.toString());
    System.out.println(interfac.isAssignableFrom(dialect));
}
```

Will print:

```
class org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
class org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
false          <- ah, its incompatible.
```

How to solve?

You can solve the nut-shell by load the interface from the **same classloader** as the first modul.

```
Class interfac = module1.loadClass("org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect");
      ...
class org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
class org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
true                 <- solved
```

### Solution

But how to solve in JBoss? There is no clean solution as long as you not provide complete access to the infrastructure for us. This would might cause some legal problems to you, please do not provide the access to the infrastructure of the project. Please use the workaround instead until you could move to Wildfly.

### Workaround

But there is a easy workaround, copy hibernate-related jars to the endorsed / ext folder of JBoss `jboss/lib/endorsed`.

This will load one hibernate for the complete jboss, any other modul will not override this base-load.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent explanation, but it did not fix my problem!